# call requires permission which may be rejected by user

Tags: java, android-studio

```
ImageButton call_btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    call_btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.callImageButton);

    call_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9876543210"));

            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

I am getting call requires permission which may be rejected by user this error please help me. I am doing phone call activity.

Answer (score 0):

Since Marshmallow, you have to ask permission from user at the time of using that service, at the time of making a phone call from activity ask for permission , if the user accepts it then proceed , else you don,t proceed forward.
If at first user denies the permission , show a message why this permissions is important and ask again, if user denies this time, then dont proceed forward.

Official Docs : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Check Permissions Now
     //     show an alert dialog box , telling user why this permission is imp if he/she denies the permission first time.
        return false;
    }
```